# C++ Overriding function with different return type than in base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [it is possible to change return type when override a virtual function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222279/it-is-possible-to-change-return-type-when-override-a-virtual-function-in-c)

I am getting error:

```
error: conflicting return type specified for âvirtual bool D::Show()
7: error: overriding âvirtual void A::Show()"
```

When i compile my code. The code is :

```
class A
{
       public:  
       virtual void Show()
       {
        std::cout<<"\n Class A Show\n";
       }
};

class B :  public A
{
    public:
    void Show(int i)
    {
            std::cout<<"\n Class B Show\n";
    }
};

class C
{
    public:
    virtual bool Show()=0;
};

class D :public C, public B
{
    public:
        bool Show(){
            std::cout<<"\n child Show\n";
            return true;}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.Show();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use Show() function from class C. Where is my error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4222307/1231073

Answer (score 6):

Your compiler is complaining because the two functions don't have the same return types: one of them returns a `void` and the other one returns a `bool`.  Your two functions should have the **same return type**.

You should have

```
class A {
   public:  
   virtual bool Show() {
      std::cout<<"\n Class A Show\n";
      return true; // You then ignore this return value
   }
};

class B :  public A {
   public:
   bool Show(int i) {
      std::cout<<"\n Class B Show\n";
      return true; // You then ignore this return value
   }
};
```

If you can't change classes `A` and `B`, you can change classes `C` and `D` to have a `void Show()` method instead of a `bool Show()` method.

If you can't do any of these things, you can use [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance): have a member of type `B` inside your `D` function instead of inheriting from it:

```
class D : public C {
public:
    bool Show() {
        std::cout<<"\n child Show\n";
        return true;
    }
    void ShowB() {
        b.Show();
    }

private:
    B b;
};
```

Comment: no i cant change the return type of the functions...i have use this code and i want to use the show function of class C in my child class..

Comment: You can try composition: have a member of type `B` inside your `D` function instead of inheriting from `B`

Comment: hmm thats what i m thinking..ny ways thanks a lot for ur quick help..:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a middle man.
Something like:

```
class C1 : public C{
public:
    virtual bool show(){ /* magic goes here */ }
};

class D: public C1, public B{
....
```

To call Show, you will need something like:
`static_cast<C&>(c).Show();`