# Returning different iterators with virtual derived methods

Tags: c++, oop, iterator

Say I have a virtual base class `Base`, which will in part behave like a container, with two derived classes `VectorLike` and `RangeLike`.
I want to achieve something like the following:

```
class VectorLike : public Base {
    std::vector<int> data;
public:
    virtual std::vector<int>::const_iterator cbegin() { return data.cbegin() }
    virtual std::vector<int>::const_iterator cend() { return data.cend() }
}

class RangeLike : public Base {
    int min, max;
    class const_iterator {
        int x;
    public:
        int operator++() { return ++x }
        bool operator==( const_iterator rhs ) { return x == rhs.x }
        const_iterator( int y ) { x = y }
    }
public:
    virtual const_iterator cbegin() { return const_iterator( min ); }
    virtual const_iterator cend() { return const_iterator( max ); }
}
```

This code will not compile, since `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` and `RangeLike::const_iterator` aren't identical or [covariant](http://www.lwithers.me.uk/articles/covariant.html).
To achieve the second, I would need an iterator base class from which both `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` and `RangeLike::const_iterator` will derive. But then still `cbegin()` and `cend()` will have to return pointers to iterators, which will make an even bigger mess.

My question is, is it possible to achieve something like the above code and if so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [it is possible to change return type when override a virtual function in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222279/it-is-possible-to-change-return-type-when-override-a-virtual-function-in-c)

Comment: You'll need your own polymorphic iterator type that wraps the vector iterator and the range iterator

Comment: In that case the derived classes need to be known beforehand. If I decide to introduce a third derived class, I have to edit the base iterator. That, and I basically store double the iterators I want to store, which hardly seems optimal.

Comment: use the 'inheritance is an implementation detail' idiom. full instructions and examples here:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an implementation of a polymorphic const int iterator. You can construct it with any iterator type (including pointers) where `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type` resolves to `int`.

This should be the case for both `std::vector<int>` and `your_range_type<int>`.

This should get you started.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

struct poly_const_iterator
{
    using value_type = int;

    struct concept {
        virtual void next(int n) = 0;
        virtual const value_type& deref() const = 0;
        virtual bool equal(const void* other) const = 0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<concept> clone() const = 0;
        virtual const std::type_info& type() const = 0;
        virtual const void* address() const = 0;
        virtual ~concept() = default;
    };

    template<class Iter>
    struct model : concept
    {
        model(Iter iter) : _iter(iter) {}

        void next(int n) override { _iter = std::next(_iter, n); }
        const value_type& deref() const override { return *_iter; }
        bool equal(const void* rp) const override { return _iter == static_cast<const model*>(rp)->_iter; }
        std::unique_ptr<concept> clone() const override { return std::make_unique<model>(*this); }
        const std::type_info& type() const override { return typeid(_iter); }
        const void* address() const override { return this; }


        Iter _iter;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<concept> _impl;

public:
    // interface

    // todo: constrain Iter to be something that iterates value_type
    template<class Iter>
    poly_const_iterator(Iter iter) : _impl(std::make_unique<model<Iter>>(iter)) {};

    poly_const_iterator(const poly_const_iterator& r) : _impl(r._impl->clone()) {};

    const value_type& operator*() const {
        return _impl->deref();
    }

    poly_const_iterator& operator++() {
        _impl->next(1);
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const poly_const_iterator& r) const {
        return _impl->type() == r._impl->type()
        and _impl->equal(r._impl->address());
    }

    bool operator != (const poly_const_iterator& r) const {
        return not(*this == r);
    }
};

void emit(poly_const_iterator from, poly_const_iterator to)
{
    std::copy(from, to, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::array<int, 5> a = { 6, 7,8, 9, 0 };

    emit(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    emit(std::begin(a), std::end(a));


    return 0;
}
```

expected results:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
6, 7, 8, 9, 0,
```

Comment: That's perfect! You force inheritance through a template class and then neatly wrap an iterator class around the pointer. Usage in emit looks really clean too.

Comment: don't forget to add a move constructor, assignment and move-assignment operators. sorry I forgot those.

Comment: @RichardHodges How would you implement going past the end and setting the iterator into state such that it compares equal to the 'end' iterator which corresponds to the default constructed iterator?

Comment: I don't think that's  possible

Comment: @RichardHodges I have a crazy setup where I pass std::function from poly_const_iterator to model that's to be called when the end is reached. I'm assuming the iterator knows when that is, as it knows how many elements are in the container. The lambda I pass is `[this]{ _impl.reset(); }` so the model gets deleted from within itself, similar to calling `delete this;` but with the benefit of setting the pointer to null which in turn makes it evaluate equal to default constructed iterator. But I was hoping you had something less insane :)

Comment: @NikolaSmiljanić The problem is that std container iterators don't compare equal to container.end() when they are default-initialised (if indeed they can be). One way to get around this would be to pass a reference to the container into the Model, so we could know that the iterator model 'is one past the end'

Comment: @RichardHodges Yeah I'm going for stream iterator interface where there's no real 'end' iterator that the container can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a C++20 based solution (partial implementation)... just thought I'd put it out there.

It uses a variant with stack storage rather than polymorphism and dynamic allocation, so it might have better performance.

It should work for any given set of iterator types that have a common `value_type` and whose `reference` type is `value_type&`. It should also be fairly easy to adapt for other types of iterator and to include `operator->`.

Not claiming this is better than the implementation in the original answer. Merely an interesting alternative...

PS. `normal` in the names below simply indicates a basic pointer based iterator.

```
  template <typename _Iterator, typename _Value, typename _Reference, typename _Difference>
  concept forward_iterator_for
    = std::forward_iterator<_Iterator>
      && std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<_Iterator>, _Value>
      && std::same_as<std::iter_reference_t<_Iterator>, _Reference>
      && std::same_as<std::iter_difference_t<_Iterator>, _Difference>;

  template <typename _Iterator, typename _Value>
  concept normal_forward_iterator_for //
    = std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<_Value>, std::remove_const_t<_Value>>
      && forward_iterator_for<_Iterator, std::remove_const_t<_Value>, _Value&, std::ptrdiff_t>;

  template <typename _Value, normal_forward_iterator_for<_Value> ... _Iterator>
  class normal_forward_iterator_variant {
   public:
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = std::remove_cv_t<_Value>;
    using reference         = _Value&;
    using iterator_type     = std::variant<_Iterator...>;

   private:
    iterator_type _m_iter;

   public:
    normal_forward_iterator_variant() = default;

    template <normal_forward_iterator_for<_Value> _Iter, typename... _Args>
    normal_forward_iterator_variant(std::in_place_type_t<_Iter>, _Args&&... args)
    noexcept (std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<_Iter, _Args&&...>)
    : _m_iter(std::in_place_type<_Iter>, std::forward<_Args>(args)...) {}

    normal_forward_iterator_variant(iterator_type const& iter)
    noexcept (std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<iterator_type>)
    : _m_iter(iter) {}

    normal_forward_iterator_variant(normal_forward_iterator_variant const&) = default;

    normal_forward_iterator_variant(normal_forward_iterator_variant&&) = default;

    constexpr normal_forward_iterator_variant&
    operator=(normal_forward_iterator_variant const& iter)
    noexcept (std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<iterator_type>) //
    requires std::is_copy_assignable_v<iterator_type> {
      _m_iter = iter._m_iter;
      return *this;
    }

    constexpr normal_forward_iterator_variant&
    operator=(normal_forward_iterator_variant&& iter)
    noexcept (std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<iterator_type>) //
    requires std::is_move_assignable_v<iterator_type> {
      _m_iter = std::move(iter._m_iter);
      return *this;
    }

    template <typename _Tp>
    constexpr normal_forward_iterator_variant&
    operator=(_Tp const& x)
    noexcept (std::is_nothrow_assignable_v<iterator_type, _Tp&>) //
    requires std::is_assignable_v<iterator_type, _Tp&> {
      _m_iter = x;
      return *this;
    }

    template <typename _Tp>
    constexpr normal_forward_iterator_variant&
    operator=(_Tp&& x)
    noexcept (std::is_nothrow_assignable_v<iterator_type, _Tp&&>) //
    requires std::is_assignable_v<iterator_type, _Tp&&> {
      _m_iter = std::move(x);
      return *this;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference
    operator*() const noexcept {
      return std::visit([](auto&& iter) -> reference {
        return *iter;
      }, _m_iter);
    }

    constexpr normal_forward_iterator_variant&
    operator++() noexcept {
      std::visit([](auto&& iter) {
        ++iter;
      }, _m_iter);
      return *this;
    }

    constexpr normal_forward_iterator_variant
    operator++(int) noexcept {
      normal_forward_iterator_variant rv(*this);
      ++*this;
      return rv;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] friend constexpr bool
    operator==(normal_forward_iterator_variant const& a, normal_forward_iterator_variant const& b) noexcept {
      return (a._m_iter == b._m_iter);
    }
  };
```

Example use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

#include <iterator.h>

int
main() {
  using vector   = std::vector<int>;
  using list     = std::list<int>;
  using iterator = normal_forward_iterator_variant<const int, vector::const_iterator, list::const_iterator>;

  iterator iter;

  vector v{ 0, 1, 2 };
  iter = v.cbegin();
  std::cout << *iter++ << std::endl;
  std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
  std::cout << *++iter << std::endl;

  list l{ 3, 4, 5 };
  iter = l.cbegin();
  std::cout << *iter++ << std::endl;
  std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
  std::cout << *++iter << std::endl;
}
```

Output is 1, 2, ..., 6 as expected.

Comment: Come to think of it, should probably include an `iterator_concept` alias too...